# Date format in LaTeX

Tags: languages, datetime

I use `UKenglish` package. And the `\date` command produces the date like so: `10th October 2011`. But I want just `10 October 2011`; `th` should be omitted. How can this be done? I tried using `datetime` package. But couldn't eliminate `th` in the date.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The [`isodate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate) allows for various formatting of language-specific dates. The command `\cleanlookdateon` removes the ordinal numbering of the day and simply prints it as a numeric:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel
\usepackage[UKenglish]{isodate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate
\begin{document}
Original date format: \today \par
\cleanlookdateon% Remove ordinal day reference
Modified date format: \today
\end{document}
```

[image: Modified UK date]

Comment: What about other languages?

Comment: @TomBrito: See [How to generate the date in Portuguese?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86173/5764)

Comment: I am trying to simply change the `/` for `.` in the date format. I use `\usepackage[num,german]{isodate}` and `\isodash{.}` but the output of `\today` is still `28/12/2013`. Why? All this in a `scrlttr2` using `\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}`, `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage{babel}` if that information is important.

Comment: I see that I was confused above. I now don't use `isodash{}` as I don't ask for an ISO format. However, I can't make it work (any change) for example with `\numdate\today` when I previously set, for example, `\daymonthsepgerman{$\cdot$}%`. Any hints?

Comment: Well, I forgot to add the "german" option for `scrlttr2` :-). It now works.

Comment: Haha! And now the problem is that various "terms" (speak, koma-script variables) are also translated into German! How can I influence only the date?

Answer (score 17):

With the `datetime` package this could be done like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{datetime}

\begin{document}
\today

vs.

\newdateformat{UKvardate}{%
\THEDAY\ \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
\UKvardate
\today
\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Write this after loading **babel**:

```
\renewcommand\dateUKenglish{\def\today{\number\day~%
 \ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space
 \number\year}}
\dateUKenglish
```

Another way is to use the **datetime** package:

```
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\let\dateUKenglish\relax
\newdateformat{dateUKenglish}{\THEDAY~\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
```

Undefining `\dateUKenglish` is necessary in order to redefine it with `\newdateformat`.