# How to generate the date in portuguese?

Tags: languages, datetime

TexStudio will generate the date like "December 8, 2012", and I need it to generate in Portuguese, like "8 de Dezembro de 2012".

How can I configure that? ([`isodate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate) package doesn't contain Portuguese)

**Related:** [Date format in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31137/date-format-in-latex)

Comment: Is this problem close related with TeXStudio? If not I suggest to edit the title and remove it. Try my suggestion below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Load `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}`.