# Query regarding usage of \date

Tags: datetime

Hi I am using Texmaker to create some documents. When I use `\date{text}` the `text` being any date, and then run the `.tex` file I don't see the date in the PDF file. It's just blank. Not sure why. Is there a specific package to use `\date`?

Answer (score 10):

`\date` merely sets the date and doesn't print it, just like `\title` and `\author` also doesn't typeset anything. Actually, `\date` stores its value in `\@date`, which you can retrieve if you don't use `\maketitle` (since it acts in a self-destruct fashion, wiping out most of the title-related information after its usage). If you which to print it, you could define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printdate}{\@date}
\makeatother
```

in your preamble and use `\printdate` wherever you want to show the date specified through `\date`.

However, the best way to access the date and print it in various formats, is to use the [`isodate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate). See [Date format in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31137/5764).

Answer (score 9):

`\date{}` only sets the date but does not print it. The most common way of doing so is `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\date{24.12.2012}
\title{Some example}
\author{Uwe Ziegenhagen}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

If you want to access the date (or author or title) outside the titlepage have a look at the `titling` package. It provides new commands such as `\thedate`.

BTW: TeXmaker is only the editor, it has nothing to do with LaTeX behind.