# Change date format

Tags: formatting, datetime

How can I display certain dates as `2000/12` instead of `30. Dezember 2000`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2000-12-30} %Prints as expected: 30. Dezember 2000

\DTMdate{2000-12-30} %Should be printed as: 2000/12

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, `\date` does not have an optional argument, neither by standard LaTeX nor by the `datetime` additions.

Comment: Note also that `\date` on its own doesn't actually typeset anything. It only sets what should be displayed by `\maketitle`.

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Query regarding usage of \date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88282/query-regarding-usage-of-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to define a new style, and then change style in the document. Either change it within a group or environment to keep the style change local, or change back to `default` afterwards.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{yyyymm}{%
\renewcommand\DTMdisplaydate[4]{##1/\DTMtwodigits{##2}}%
\renewcommand\DTMDisplaydate[4]{##1/\DTMtwodigits{##2}}%
}

\begin{document}

\DTMdate{2000-12-30} %Should be printed as: 2000/12

{% pair of braces makes the new style local
\DTMsetdatestyle{yyyymm}
\DTMdate{2000-12-30}
}

\DTMdate{2000-12-30}

\DTMsetdatestyle{yyyymm}
\DTMdate{2000-12-30}

% or you can set the style back to default
\DTMsetdatestyle{default}
\DTMdate{2000-12-30}


\end{document}
```