# How to drop "st", "nd", and "th" from the default date format in British English in bibliography with babel+biber+biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, languages, date

According to [Cambridge Grammar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/writing/dates), the most common way of writing dates is as follows:

> 20 January 1993

and not

> <strike>20th January 1993</strike>

However, the "th" is still produced by biber+biblatex by default:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mybook,
    author      =   {Author},
    date        =   {1993-01-20},
    title       =   {Wonderful Tiny Fact (WTF)}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{mybook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result is shown below:
[image: result of running the pdflatex-biber-pdflatex loop]

While I am not arguing for or against the full stop after "Jan", I am arguing that using "th" is AGAINST the most widespread style. In addition to the above Grammar link, see [the editorial style of the university of Bath](http://www.bath.ac.uk/guides/editorial-style-guide/), which explicitly forbids it. My British English teacher also explicitly considers it wrong.

Of course, there might be a technical solution to omit "th" (see [Date format in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31137/date-format-in-latex) for the main text).

1. How to omit the suffixes ("st", "nd", and "th") in dates in the bibliography?
2. Can the current **default** setting of printing "th" actually be classified as a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure the second part is on-topic for us: style decisions are down to package authors and are also difficult to classify as bugs. (As a UK national I'm not keen on this move toward omitting the "th" part, though of course for a standard setting its not what one likes but what 'is' that drives things.)

Comment: To be honest, given the huge range of university and journal house styles, it doesn't matter what the default is so long as it's clearly defined and we can adjust it to match our requirements. Others may require the ordinal suffix to be superscripted, for example.

Comment: That page is also rather odd - it permits shortenting of *July* but not *June*, a system that's rarely followed.

Comment: @LeonMeierthe Cambridge link at the top of your Q: *With the exception of May and June, months can be shortened as follows:

Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec.* (I'd forgotten about the other external link byt he time I wrote that comment)

Comment: @LeonMeier I use it as an example to treat the page (and indeed *any* style guide) with a degree of caution, while supporting the aspects of the question that are about adjusting the output.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Set `dateabbrev=false` option to use January instead of Jan. Ordinal numbers are not used by Australian style. So we can just copy the date definition from australian.lbx, like this:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
% dateabbrev=false will stop abbreviation of months
\usepackage[backend=biber,dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mybook,
    author      =   {Author},
    date        =   {1993-01-20},
    title       =   {Wonderful Tiny Fact (WTF)}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% Taken from australian.lbx which does not use ordinal numbers
\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondateshort#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondatelong#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite{mybook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: leave `dateabbrev=false` out of the `biblatex` options.